# No /dev/video* in Arch Linux on Dell XPS 13 Plus (9320)

Tags: arch-linux, camera

I finally got the new Dell XPS Plus, I've installed Arch Linux (with Xfce4) but it seems like that are no recognizable webcams or video devices, even though the laptop has a built-in one + IR camera.

Looking up anything online either leads to dead-ends (e.g. no actual solutions are given), suggestions of some killswitch (which does not exist on this laptop, it seems to me), or in one case a suggestion to install `upd72020x-fw` which did nothing for me.

I know that this is "earlyadopterisis" kind of situation, but if anyone has any idea what could cause this problem and what can I do to resolve it, or at least how to pinpoint the actual problem first, that would be great.

Let me also add that the BIOS setup seem to recognize the webcam, but I'm not 100% sure if it really does, or if it's just recognizing the setup option for it to be on, and since there is no webcam test in the BIOS itself, I'm not quite sure what to do there. Unfortunately, I don't think I've tested the webcam before installing Arch.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I don't think I've tested the webcam before installing Arch.":

I had the same issue and did revert to Dell's original Ubuntu image for the XPS 13 plus. Result: Camera works. It identifies as an Intel MIPI camera on Intel's Alder Lake platform. Not sure how to make it work on Arch Linux though.

Comment: Thanks. And thank you for raising this on the Arch Linux forums! (I assume.)

Comment: Yes, that was me. Here's the link https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=277462

Comment: I have to agree with https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2059361#p2059361, I haven't had Linux (and especially Arch) make me feel regret about hardware issues for a very very long time.